# How can I pass collected values to a replanned action?

Tags: bixby, bixbystudio

When the user says "read john 3:100", I have a ReadBibleVerse action that matches `book:john`, `chapter:3`, `verse:100`. The endpoint will return a 404, since there is no verse 100.

I want that action to capture the error and `replan` to a "read chapter" request, passing along `book:john` and `chapter:3`.

What I have...

```
action (ReadBibleVerse) {
  collect {
    input (book) {…}
    input (chapter) { type (ChapterNum) … }
    input (verse) {…}
  }
  output (Scripture) {
    throws {
      unknown-error {
        on-catch {
          replan {
            dialog ("Unknown verse, trying the chapter.")
            intent {
              goal: Scripture
              route: ReadBibleChapter
}}}}}}}
```

…what I get is "Unknown verse, trying the chapter. I need a book to continue."

I'm clearly hitting the error and, I believe, being "replanned" to ReadBibleChapter, but I'm also getting "I need a book to continue." because I need to explicitly pass along `book` and `chapter`?

I found [intent.value](https://bixbydevelopers.com/dev/docs/reference/type/intent.value), which appears to solve my problem, except I can't seem to find the correct format:

- `value: ChapterNum`
- `value: ChapterNum (chapter)`
- `value: [namespace].ChapterNum { $expr(chapter) }`
- more various nonsense
- …

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work `value {$expr(chapter)}`

Comment: I assume you mean `value: {$expr(chapter)}`? But I get a couple errors with that format: `invalid type name: '', not a structure type: null`

ChapterNum is a primitive (int), so do you mean `value: ChapterNum({$expr(chapter)})`? That tells me I'm _missing closing ")"_

Comment: Whatthe... ok, so I tried it (despite being obviously wrong format), and it worked. Documentation says a `:` is needed—and I'm super confused as it why it's not.

Comment: I have not tried this but value: $expr(chapter) *should* work too. This area of documentation needs a bit of additional information to make it clearer. We will work on getting this included.

Comment: OR value: ChapterNum{$expr(chapter)} should work too.

Comment: i just get `Error: Not a structure type: ChapterNum`

Comment: You can use value-set: ChapterNum{$expr(chapter)} for that one.